# Compare date ranges for overlap but allowing adjacent ranges

Tags: c#, date, range, overlap

In simple terms i have a date range object which stores a start/end date.
I want to  compare 2 date ranges for no overlap, but also allowing adjacent ranges where the first range end date is equal to the 2nd range start date.

Range 1 = 1/1/2016 10:00AM - 1/1/2016 10:30AM
Range 2 = 1/1/2016 10:30AM - 1/1/2016 11:30AM

I've hada a few goes at creating a c# function but cant seem to get it working right.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: And what do you have for now?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
public class DateRange
{
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    public bool Overlaps(DateRange otherRange)
    {
        if (StartDate < otherRange.EndDate && StartDate >= otherRange.StartDate)
            return true;
        if (otherRange.StartDate < EndDate && otherRange.StartDate >= StartDate)
            return true;
        if (EndDate > otherRange.StartDate && EndDate <= otherRange.EndDate)
            return true;
        if (otherRange.EndDate < StartDate && otherRange.EndDate >= EndDate)
            return true;

        return false;                
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Works great :-) thanks for your help. i've tested the above code with the following scenarios:

//this needs to take into the account the following range scenarios
//1. range1 start in range2 and finishes whenever
//2. range2 starts in range1 and finishes whenever
//3. range1 starts before range2 start and finishes in or after range2
//4. range2 starts before range1 start and finishes in or after range1
//5. range1 fully overlaps range2
//6. range2 fully overlaps range1

It should allow adjacent ranges where r1 end equals r2 start.